# List of transactions from the block that just has been mined and broadcasted but not confirmed yet

Tags: transactions, mining, parity, json-rpc

I'm looking for a list of transactions from the block that just has been mined but not confirmed yet. 
Right now I'm using JSON RPC method `parity_pendingTransaction` to return a list of transactions currently in the queue.

However let's consider the following scenario (in ideal world:)

- Node A - my parity client
- Node B, C - some miners

There is 500 transactions in the pool (sorted by `gasPrice` in the descending order)

- `00:00:29.999` - **Node A** calls `parity_pendingTransaction` (get's 500
  transactions - `transaction_list1`)
- `00:00:30` - block 100 has been mined
  by **Node B** (node included 300 out of 500 transactions)
- `00:00:30.001` - Node B is broadcasting to other nodes (including Node A) that block has been mined, so it could be verified by others
- `00:00:35` - **Node A** calls `parity_pendingTransaction` (get's 500 transactions - `transaction_list2`)
- `00:00:45` block 101 has been mined by **Node C**
- `00:00:46` - **Node A** calls `parity_pendingTransaction` (get's X
  transactions - `transaction_list3`)

Long story short: Because the next block is mined in `00:00:45` I don't know, which transactions has been included in block 100 until `00:00:45` (so `transaction_list1 == transaction_list2`).

Is there a way to retrive that information, after **Node B** broadcasts that block 100 has been mined.?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, couldn't just look up which transactions are included in block 100?

Comment: TBH I'm not sure if I understand correctly the way mining in Etherum works. 
For example if I create a transaction at `00:00:25` and it's included in block 100, it will change status from `Pending` in i.e. `etherscan.io`, once it's confirmed at least 1 time (which is `00:00:45`)

My questions is: can I somehow know/discover in parity that this transaction has been included in block 100. I would like to get this information before `00:00:45`. The sooner the better. Thanks!

Comment: No, block 100 that includes the transaction is already the first confirmation at `00:00:30`, block 101 is confirmation 2. There is no intermediate step.